# I want to build a new island country in the ocean. Where is the best place to build it?

Tags: oceanography, islands

It should be far enough away from land so that another country may not stake claim on the island, but in a shallow enough area such that dredging and depositing sand and other building materials is relatively easy.

Comment: Welcome Anand Sharma to Earth Science Stack Exchange. Does this answer your question? [Are there seamounts as close as 100 m to the water surface and not inside any Exclusive Economic Zone?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/16256/27775).